# Is my antlr4 visitor code incorrect? It produces the wrong value but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong

Tags: c#, antlr4

My grammar for simple math expression is:

```
grammar Arithmetics;

expr : term (PLUS term | MINUS term)*;
term : factor (MULT factor | DIV factor)*;
factor : INT;

PLUS : '+';
MINUS : '-';
MULT : '*';
DIV : '/';

INT : [0-9]+;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

My code is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "1 + 2 * 3 - 8 / 4";
        var lexer = new ArithmeticsLexer(new AntlrInputStream(input));
        var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new ArithmeticsParser(tokens);

        var tree = parser.expr();

        Console.WriteLine(tree.ToStringTree(parser));

        var visitor = new MyArithmeticsVisitor();
        int result = visitor.Visit(tree);

        Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
    }
}

public class MyArithmeticsVisitor : ArithmeticsBaseVisitor<int>
{
    public override int VisitExpr(ArithmeticsParser.ExprContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Expr:{context.GetText()}");
        int result = VisitTerm(context.term(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < context.term().Length; i++)
        {
            String s = context.term(i).GetText();
            Console.WriteLine($"Visiting term {s}");

            if (context.PLUS(i) != null)
                result += VisitTerm(context.term(i));
            else if (context.MINUS(i) != null)
                result -= VisitTerm(context.term(i));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override int VisitTerm(ArithmeticsParser.TermContext context)
    {
        int result = VisitFactor(context.factor(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < context.factor().Length; i++)
        {
            if (context.MULT(i - 1) != null)
                result *= VisitFactor(context.factor(i));
            else if (context.DIV(i - 1) != null)
                result /= VisitFactor(context.factor(i));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override int VisitFactor(ArithmeticsParser.FactorContext context)
    {
        string strFactor = context.INT().GetText();
        Console.WriteLine($"factor {strFactor}");
        return int.Parse(strFactor);
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
(expr (term (factor 1)) + (term (factor 2) * (factor 3)) - (term (factor 8) / (factor 4)))
Expr:1+2*3-8/4
factor 1
Visiting term 2*3
Visiting term 8/4
Result: 1
```

I am confused about my implementation of VisitExpr(). Terms are visited correctly, but it is clear that I am searching for lexer operators PLUS and MIN incorrectly; I can't figure out how to do it right.
Any advise / help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The operator lists (`PLUS`, `MIN`, etc.) do not have the same length as the `term` or `factor` lists. Besides, when the `PLUS` list contains elements, you try to fetch it with index `i` that starts with 1, whereas `PLUS` should start with 0: `PLUS[i - 1]`.

You can add all operators in the same `op` list like this:

```
parse : expr EOF; // Always good to have a start-rule with an EOF
expr : term (op+=PLUS term | op+=MINUS term)*;
term : factor (op+=MULT factor | op+=DIV factor)*;
```

For the input `"1 + 2 - 3 + 4"`, the list returned by `term()` will contain `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. And the `op` list (or `_op` for C#) will be: `[+, -, +]`.

And then in your visitor you do:

```cs
public class MyArithmeticsVisitor : ArithmeticsBaseVisitor<int>
{
  // You can just call the base Visit() method on your child contexts!

  public override int VisitParse(ArithmeticsParser.ParseContext context)
    => base.Visit(context.expr());

  public override int VisitExpr(ArithmeticsParser.ExprContext context)
  {
    var result = this.Visit(context.term(0));

    for (var index = 1; index < context.term().Length; index++)
    {
      if (context._op[index - 1].Type == ArithmeticsParser.PLUS)
        result += this.Visit(context.term(index));
      else
        result -= this.Visit(context.term(index));
    }

    return result;
  }

  public override int VisitTerm(ArithmeticsParser.TermContext context)
  {
    var result = this.Visit(context.factor(0));

    for (var index = 1; index < context.factor().Length; index++)
    {
      if (context._op[index - 1].Type == ArithmeticsParser.MULT)
        result *= this.Visit(context.factor(index));
      else
        result /= this.Visit(context.factor(index));
    }

    return result;
  }

  public override int VisitFactor(ArithmeticsParser.FactorContext context)
    => int.Parse(context.INT().GetText());
}
```

retuslting in the correct answer: 5.

However, ANTLR4 supports direct left recursion, making things a lot easier to understand:

```
parse : expr EOF;

expr
 : expr (MULT | DIV) expr
 | expr (PLUS | MINUS) expr
 | INT
 ;

PLUS : '+';
MINUS : '-';
MULT : '*';
DIV : '/';

INT : [0-9]+;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Your visitor could then look like this:

```cs
public class MyArithmeticsVisitor : ArithmeticsBaseVisitor<int>
{
  public override int VisitParse(ArithmeticsParser.ParseContext context)
    => base.Visit(context.expr());

  public override int VisitExpr(ArithmeticsParser.ExprContext context)
  {
    if (context.INT() != null)
      return int.Parse(context.INT().GetText());

    if (context.MULT() != null)
      return Visit(context.expr(0)) * Visit(context.expr(1));

    if (context.DIV() != null)
      return Visit(context.expr(0)) / Visit(context.expr(1));

    if (context.PLUS() != null)
      return Visit(context.expr(0)) + Visit(context.expr(1));

    return Visit(context.expr(0)) - Visit(context.expr(1));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will digest your answer to make sure I fully understand it.

Comment: Sure, let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: First of all, thank you again for clarifications. You also showed me how to use labels, I was not familiar with them. My first question is related to the usage of indexing into the "term". You wrote:
for (var index = 1; index < context.term().Length; index++)
    {
      if (context._op[index - 1].Type == ArithmeticsParser.PLUS)
...
When writing the code to process term - are you looking in the term from the standpoint of grammar, where the first token is always a PLUS or MIN and second a factor? Each term in my example can have only two children?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. I added some extra information about the `op` list that collects the operators. Perhaps that answers your question.